# (javascript) If you had a string that was a word with a number at the end. How would you add a space between the word and the number?

Tags: javascript, string

For example:

```
let word = 'Winter4000'

const seperate = (word) => {
  ...
}

seperate(word) // output: Winter 4000
```

The word can be random and the number is always at the end.

Comment: You could naively iterate through `word` and check if the character you are looking at is a number or not. As soon as you see the first number you now at what index the word ends and the number starts.

Comment: `word.split()` using a nice regex pattern, like this one `(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ian's answer works for most integers, but for decimals or numbers with commas (like 1,000,000), you'll want an expression like

```
word.split(/([0-9.,]+)/).join(" ");
```

so it doesn't put an extra space when it runs into a decimal point or comma.

Writing this as a function,

```
let word = 'Winter4,000.000';

const seperate = (input_word) => {
    return input_word.split(/([0-9.,]+)/).join(" ");
}

console.log(seperate(word));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let word = 'Winter4000'
const seperate = word.split(/([0-9]+)/).join(" ")
```

split it using regex pattern looking for numbers, then join it back together with a space added

Comment: The solution will have a space in the end of the result string.

Answer (score 0):

```
const word = 'Winter4000';
const result = word.match(/[^\d]+/) + ' ' + word.match(/[\d]+/);
```